# opencart 2 problems with vqmod / ocmod, when DIR_CATALOG used in webshop

Tags: logging, opencart, vqmod

Finally I found why an admin extension was giving a blanc screen on the home page of a webshop.

Nothing wrong with that extension, just some changes in some admin programs in ocmod.

But the strange thing is without that extension no notice errors are logged in error.log. When I install that admin extension, than notice errors (from different programs) are logged in error.log

First showing errors was set on, so with that admin extension the notice errors were also displayed and that was giving a blanc screen because of compression set on (no echo's allowed before sending headers).

So the question is now finally, why are notice errors never logged but only when I just install that admin extension in ocmod. I see that this extension have also changed two language files, I see that changed files in system/modifications but not in vqcache. Is there something going strange in ocmod, or do you see not always all the files in vqcache ?

Comment: Do you use both  `vqmod` and `ocmod` ?

Comment: Ved Pandya, yes both.

Comment: There is progress meanwhile. I detected VQMOD is taking the wrong sources sometimes e.g. for model catalog/product in the webshop, the admin model catalog/product have been taken (in some multishops, not all) .. but still strange is, only when I install that new admin extension in OCMOD (working well and nothing wrong with it in admin) ..

Comment: Problem solved. My customer had added the DIR_CATALOG in the config.php of the webshop. There is a method modification in system/startup.php, where DIR_CATALOG is used to determine the webshop or the admin environment. Therefore wrong path's are composed for vqmod/ocmod. Now all my problems are solved, in fact there were no notice errors in error.log, this was because of the wrong model source found .. my admin extension had a ocmod change in model catalog/product, so because of the error that model was used in the webshop and was giving all the notice errros ..